# Convert double point coordinates into string

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
string Point::ToString(const Point& pt)
{
    std::stringstream buffX;  //"Incomplete type is not allowed"????
    buffX << pt.GetX(); // no operator "<<" matches these operands????
    std::stringstream buffY;
    buffY << pt.GetY();

    string temp = "Point(" + buffX + ", " + buffY + ")";  //???....how to combine a couple of strings into one?..
    return temp.str();
}
```

I followed the code from similar questions, but the system says "Incomplete type is not allowed"---red line under buffX

also red line under "<<" says that---- no operator "<<" matches these operands

really don't know why..

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You need to `#include <sstream>` to use [`std::ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/).

Then:

```
std::string Point::ToString(const Point& pt)
{
    std::ostringstream temp;
    temp << "Point(" << pt.GetX() << ", " << pt.GetY() << ")"; 
    return temp.str();
}
```

It's not clear why you're passing in a `Point`, since this is a member of that class. Perhaps cleaner would be:

```
std::string Point::ToString() const
{
    std::ostringstream temp;
    temp << "Point(" << GetX() << ", " << GetY() << ")"; 
    return temp.str();
}
```

This, perhaps incorrectly, assumes that `GetX()` and `GetY()` `return` some kind of numeric type (`int`, `float`, `double`, ...). If this is not the case, you may want to either change them (the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)) or access the underlying data members of the `class` directly.

If you're struggling with this kind of compiler error, I strongly recommend you get yourself [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer!

I did include <sstream>. Now a new problem comes up..


std::string Point::ToString() const
{

    std::ostringstream temp;

    temp << "Point(" << GetX() << ", " << GetY() << ")"; 
// red line under temp says this declaration has no storage or type specifier????

    return temp.str();  //expect a declaration???
}

Comment: @Kun: It's hard to make head or tail of that output, but it suggests to me that your `Get?()`s are not actually returning anything. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time!! I figured out what was wrong today.. I missed the semi-colon when define the class point... again, thank you!